# Can't install Jupyter Notebook in Atom

Tags: atom, jupyter

I can't install Jupyter Notebook in Atom. I get these errors.

```
bufferutil@1.2.1 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/bufferutil  
node-gyp rebuild  

utf-8-validate@1.2.2 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/utf-8-validate  
node-gyp rebuild  

pathwatcher@8.0.2 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/pathwatcher
node-gyp rebuild 

/tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9
└── (empty)
npm WARN deprecated jupyter-js-services@0.21.1: This package has moved to @jupyterlab/services
npm WARN deprecated phosphor@0.5.0: use @phosphor/ packages
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/python-interceptor.sh" is v3.7.0, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:454:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:443:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-30-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/python-interceptor.sh" is v3.7.0, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:454:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:443:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-30-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/python-interceptor.sh" is v3.7.0, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:454:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:443:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-30-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/pathwatcher
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9 No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9 No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9 No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 (node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/bufferutil):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 (node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/utf-8-validate):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/192/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/nikolay/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/nikolay/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-11881-6115-1fr4y32.psvjd4e7b9/package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=2.0.5" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pathwatcher@8.0.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pathwatcher@8.0.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pathwatcher package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pathwatcher
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pathwatcher
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-11881-6115-cmx7ut.qatf6tuik9/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**[jupyter-notebook](https://atom.io/packages/jupyter-notebook)** is an Atom package that works like Jupyter Notebook, but inside Atom. It's registered as an opener for .ipynb files.

To install jupyter-notebook in Ubuntu 20.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-all python3-pip jupyter-notebook jupyter     
sudo pip3 install jupyter_kernel_gateway  
apm install jupyter-notebook # or search for jupyter-notebook package inside of Atom
```

To install jupyter-notebook in Ubuntu 18.04-19.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-all python3-pip python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel  
sudo pip3 install jupyter_kernel_gateway  
apm install jupyter-notebook # or search for jupyter-notebook package inside of Atom
```

Usage:

Run cell: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you are not running Ubuntu 18.04 the instructions for installing Jupyter Notebook are a bit more complicated. Comment if you need these instructions to be added to this answer.

Comment: sir there are some errors:

Comment: 1. sudo pip3 install jupyter_kernel_gateway 
The directory '/home/nikolay/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/nikolay/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: 2. apm install jupyter-notebook
Installing jupyter-notebook to /home/nikolay/.atom/packages ✗
it gets the same error

Comment: `apm install jupyter-notebook` works in my Ubuntu 18.04. As for the `sudo -H` error message read this question: [What is the -H flag for pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619686/what-is-the-h-flag-for-pip)